# Excel return all data to another worksheet based on header name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vba

In Microsoft Excel I want to create a table to be something like in picture below.
[image: I cannot include photo in my post]

I already try using vlookup and index but I can't make it work like I want.
Please help me

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use VBA:

```
Sub TransformTbl()
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, cnt As Long

   With ActiveSheet
      .Range("G1:I1") = Array("Date", "Event", "Place")
      cnt = 1
      For j = 2 To 4      'column
         For i = 2 To 5   'row
            If Len(.Cells(i, j)) <> 0 Then
               cnt = cnt + 1
               .Cells(cnt, 7) = .Cells(1, j)  'Date
               .Cells(cnt, 8) = .Cells(i, j)  'Event
               .Cells(cnt, 9) = .Cells(i, 1)  'Place
            End If
         Next i
      Next j
   End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution and it works fine with me. The formula is really complex and probably hard to understand. Though I'll try my best to explain it, updating the formula may still be a difficult work. All these three formula are written in Array Formula, press ctrl+shift+enter to complete.

Formula in G6:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$5,0,SMALL(
IF($B$6:$D$9<>"",1,99999999)*(COLUMN($B$6:$D$9)-1),ROW(A1))),"")
```

The outer IFERROR keeps your sheet from any #Err. The OFFSET for calling the right date. The formula inside SMALL generate an array with the rule: If there is an event, the value will be the number of the date for offset, otherwise, it will be 99999999 which giving the OFFSET an error and be blocked by IFERROR. With the data you gave, the array will be

```
{        1,99999999,       3;
         1,       2,99999999;
         1,99999999,99999999;
  99999999,99999999,       3 }
```

Formula in H6:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$5,
    SMALL(IF($B$6:$D$9<>"",ROW($B$6:$D$9)-5)*
        IF(COLUMN($B$6:$D$9)=MATCH(G6,$B$5:$D$5,0)+1,1,99999999),99999999),COUNTIF($G$6:G6,G6)),
    MATCH(G6,$B$5:$D$5,0)),"")
```

The IFERROR and OFFSET works the same as G6. The formula in OFFSET.ROW generate nearly the same array as G6. This time the value is the row of event with the date determined by column G. Other gives 999999999 or more.

Formula in I6:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET($A$5,MAX((ROW($B$6:$D$9)-5)*($B$6:$D$9=H6)*
(COLUMN($B$6:$D$9)=MATCH(G6,$B$5:$D$5,0)+1)),0),"")
```

IFERROR and OFFSET are still the same. And this time only the event which matches the date and the name of itself has a value, other remains 0.

Finally, I apologize for the poor readability. Wish someone can help me out with this :]